# cfdirectory replacing spaces with + characters when action=list on an S3 folder

Tags: amazon-s3, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am uploading a file, that contains spaces in the name, to Amazon S3 using `cffile action="upload"`. The file name is `burger+beans n beetroot.jpg`. 
As you can see, the name contains spaces and a plus sign.

When I read the directory, to list the contents, the file name returned by ColdFusion in the query is: `burger+beans+n+beetroot.jpg`. However, when viewing the file using Amazon S3 Browser, it is correctly listed as: `burger+beans n beetroot.jpg`. So it appears ColdFusion is replacing the spaces with `+` signs.

Does anyone know why this happens and if there is a way to disable this? I tried using both the `DirectoryList()` method as well as the `<cfdirectory action="list">` tag, and both do this.

Please note: I am aware that the file name could be cleaned up before processing - that's a workaround, but not the solution I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Whatever process is uploading those files should be cleansing their names. It's bad form to use a plus sign, ampersand, etc. You'll run into problems in many other areas of your application.

Comment: What is your OS? I cannot reproduce your problem. Could you please provide some more context such as a short snippet of your code?

Comment: Try using `<cfDump var='#myList#'>`. Does that show the name unescaped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is not a CF problem, it's a S3 problem. They send out their file names escaped. Which makes this a non-answer.

I created a folder in a S3 bucket. Then I uploaded a file named `burger+beans n beetroot.jpg`. I can see in AWS' console the file properly named. I select it, then in the Actions menu select Download. I get the modal window. Take a look at the URL in the browser footer - the file name is escaped.

[image: escaed url]

I right-click their link and choose "Save Link As..." - the file name is escaped as well.

[image: escaped file name]

So I don't think there is anything you can do once the file is up there. You'll need to clean it before uploading. I know it's not what you want to hear.

Comment: Actually , this was exactly what I wanted to hear. You identified where the issue is occurring. Thank you very much! I thought that the issue might be in CF, but you've clearly illustrated that it lies at S3 and therefore needs to be cleaned up/escaped as the other guys suggested.

Comment: Awesome. Did you try cfdump anyway? Perhaps in the data returned there is an 'original_file_name' or some such element. I haven't used S3 in about a decade!

Comment: Yep, that's how I originally saw the issue. I read the S3 Folder in CF using cfdirectory and dumped the results, where I saw the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try URL encoding the filename, so the + sign will be converted to an url encoded space (%2b). You could use URLEncodedFormat, but make sure that the path to the file isn't urlencoded as well.